# Красим фон блока по времени /JavaScript / PHP

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

Здравствуйте,
У меня есть сайт конференции на нем расположены опросы по докладам (списком), доклады будут проводится в определенный день в определенное время.
Вопрос заключается в том как выделить блок с опросом для того доклада который идет в реальное время и еще 15 минут после его окончания.
[image: Вид опроса на сайте]

Я знаю что как и в PHP так и в JS есть глобальные переменные с датой и временем. Помогите натолкнуть на реализацию данного плана. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А wordprress имеет какое-то отношение к js? Точнее Вам поможет ответ  с реализацией на чистом js + css? А то вдруг wp использует что-то свое и обычный js не подойдет..

Comment: Не поняла суть вашего вопроса. Я указала wordpress, исходя из того что сайт создан на этой CMS, возможно это как-то поможет в реализации.